# Saddle point in German for a line in plane

Tags: soft-question

In German Sattelpunkt (= saddle-point)  refers to a point that has inflection parallel to x-axis.

$$ y' =0, y^{''}=0 $$

*for a line* in the plane.

In English it is a point *of a surface* of negative curvature.

Why the is the same translated word so conceptually different ?

In a monkey-saddle $ (K<0) $ at its center there is an inflection point, is that why ?

Comment: Your location is : USA, India  and you are asking German. Strange :P

Comment: Wikipedia says it: a saddle point is a stationary point that is not an extremum. This holds in 1D and higher dimensions.

Comment: as @YvesDaoust says, saddle point should have a universal meaning. Germans would not change it. Can you give the source of information?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören: see German Wikipedia.

Comment: You probably misunderstood one of the Wikipedia articles, as both use the same definition.

Comment: There is no visible saddle in 1D case, so in this special case it's better to call it Terrassenpunkt and keep the notion of saddle point to minimax.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, but the use of this notion is minor compared to the "critical point with indefinite Hessian", which is central in optimization and game theory.

Comment: @YvesDaoust No, the [game saddle point](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Saddle_point_in_game_theory) has nothing to do with "critical not extremum". For example, a [monkey saddle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_saddle) is not a [saddle point](https://books.google.se/books?id=fepneLL-ugkC&lpg=PA7&ots=4nvbwsmXDx&dq=game%20%22saddle%20point%22&hl=sv&pg=PA7#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: One can see the difference between eye vision and mathematical eye (logik) vision.

Comment: @ A.Γ.  but I thought monkey saddle is composed of all saddle points except at the center where ( here monkey bottom contacts ) it is  a singularity. Is it right?

Comment: @Narasimham It is negative curvature at all points, but for the saddle point is should be a critical point.

Comment: Negative curvature point and saddle point are quite the same.. only different words